# How to map those features to 32 input neurons

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've been given a assignment based on section 10.6 of the book [Neural-Symbolic
Cognitive Reasoning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540732454). Basically, I have to replicate a binary classification experiment. And to explain my issue with it, it's needed to explain the context of the problem first.

## Context of the problem

The goal is to classify the eastbound and westbound trains, each train having a set of cars as shown in [Figure 10.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qa7P.png). In order to classify a train, certain features of the train, along with features of its cars, must be considered.

**The data set contains the following attributes**:

for each train,

- (a) the number of cars (3 to 5),
- and (b) the number of different loads (1 to 4);

and for each car,

- (c) the number of wheels (2 or 3),
- (d) the length (short or long),
- (e) the shape (closed-top rectangle, open-top rectangle, double open rectangle, ellipse, engine, hexagon,jagged top, open trap, sloped top, or U-shaped),
- (f) the number of loads (0 to 3),
- and (g) the shape of the load (circle, hexagon, rectangle, or triangle).

Then, ten boolean variables describe whether any particular pair of types of load are on adjacent cars of the train (each car carries a single type of load):

- (h) there is a rectangle next to a rectangle,
- (i) a rectangle next to a triangle,
- (j) a rectangle next to a hexagon,
- (k) a rectangle next to a circle,
- (l) a triangle next to a triangle,
- (m) a triangle next to a hexagon,
- (n) a triangle next to a circle,
- (o) a hexagon next to a hexagon,
- (p) a hexagon next to a circle,
- (q) a circle next to a circle.

Finally, the class attribute may be either *east* or *west*.

## The issue

The book says that it was used

> a network containing 32 input neurons and one output neuron (denoting east) [...]. The 32 inputs encode: the number of cars in a train; the number of different loads in a train; the number of wheels, the length, and the shape of each car; the number of loads in each car; the shape of the load of each car; and the ten boolean variables described above.

**So, what I can't understand is how to map those features to 32 input neurons.** The way that I'm counting those neurons is as follows.

## How I'm mapping those features to input neurons

- 2 neurons to represent attributes (a) and (b) listed above,
- 10 neurons to represent the ten boolean variables (attribute (h) to (q)),

  and for each car:
- 5 neurons to represent attributes (c), (d), (e), (f) and (g)

Since there's at most 5 cars in each train, there should in total 25 neurons to represent the attributes (c) to (g) for each car. This way, the network would have 2 + 10 + 25 = 37 input neurons, not 32, as the book says. So, what am I getting wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Edit #1:

According to the book, the values given to the attributes are as follows:

> attributes referring to properties of cars that do not exist are assigned the value false. As usual, −1 is used to denote false and 1 to denote true in the case of boolean variables. Further, we assign values 1, 2, 3, ... to any attributes that have multiple values, in the order which they are presented above. So, in the case, for example, of the shape of the load, 1 is used to denote circle, 2 to denote hexagon, 3 to denote rectangle, and so on. Of course, for the corresponding neurons, instead of the bipolar function, we use a linear activation function h(x) = x.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was here:

> Since there's at most 5 cars in each train, there should in total 25 neurons to represent the attributes (c) to (g) for each car

The first car doesn't need the five attributes (c) to (g), because it's the engine of the train. Therefore, the network would have the expected 2 + 10 + **20** = 32 input neurons.